# send some paramets to a URL in a loop with php

Tags: php

i have a for loop that read some data from a csv file, and of course i have a url that get parameters and insert into database

URL is:

http://domain.com/resiver/getdata.php?id=30&time=1399855552&body=mytext&from=99999999&host=10000518

Now i want to know that how can i send parameters (call this url) in my loop

what i must use for this, give me some solution

**My Code**

```
$file = 'allsms.csv';
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
      //if ($i<200)
      for ($j=0; $j<count($lineArray); $j++) {
          $data2DArray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j];

      }
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ///////here i want to send parameters to a url////////
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      unset($data2DArray);
      $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code and how you plan to perform this query. Have you looked at the PHP curl documentation?

Comment: i add my code but my code is not problem, the problem is that how can i call a url in  my loop

Comment: use `curl` that helps you to send parameters to url and return the response as well.

Comment: can u please give me a sample? i used a curl but my parameters dont pass values complete and i think lenght of values was short whene i saw inserted data

Comment: People need to see your code to be able to help you. Please check out the PHP curl docs at http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php for control structures such as loops.